# Adding Layers file to MXD using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layers, walk

I tried to add several layer files to MXD file. when i run this code no error rise- but only one layer file added to the MXD and all the other 34 layer files in the workspace aren't added to the map. This is the table of content after runnig the code:

[image]

```
import arcpy,os
workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\taba\7650"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\Project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
   for filename in filenames:
       arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)))
mxd.save()
```

How can i add the layers to the Mxd?

i red

- [Add multiple Layer files in subdirectories to mxd using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130747/add-multiple-layer-files-in-subdirectories-to-mxd-using-python)
- [Finding layer file used to add layers to MXD in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/finding-layer-file-used-to-add-layers-to-mxd-in-arcpy)

Comment: Try running the code snippet that you have presented.  I think it will error first when it hits no new line after the colon in `filenames:arcpy.mapping`.

Comment: The difference between this code (once you fix the indentation) and the code at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130754/115 is that the latter looks for and adds layers from layer files.  Here you seem to be trying to look for and add layers from features classes.  I think you should set up a test script that does nothing other than try to add a single layer from a feature class.  Once you have that working it will be easier to insert a code snippet that you know works into a larger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finely, i changed the datatype into "Layer", and backspace the "mxd.save()":

```
import arcpy,os
workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\taba\7650"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\Project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype = "Layer")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)))
        print filename,'\n'   
mxd.save()
```